# Typing central european characters in Vim and printing them out

Tags: vim

For some reason, I cannot find an encoding (tried cp1250, 1252, latin1, utf-8) in which when I type central european characters in Vim (šđčćž and their upper cap counterparts) I seem to be able to print them out (either on the printer or /using Cute PDF/ as a PDF)

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

As a workarounds you could save the document (as text or exporting to HTML with `:toHTML`) and print it from a web browser.

See also the `printencoding` and `printfont` settings in Vim.

Edit: Found [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode) which clarifies working with Unicode a little more (though nothing in here on printing).

Comment: So, you're suggesting that I use "the best text editor" (as some call it) to type stuff, and then another program to actually view it?! Sorry, but that is just not acceptable. I don't have "printencoding" option (compiled with +printer but not postscript (using the largest version from vim.org on windows)

Comment: I think the key word was 'workaround'. I'm not a Vim expert by any stretch, just trying to help out.

Comment: I am beginning to think the problem is that, on Windows, only 8-bit character encodings are supported for printing (`+postscript` is required for multi-byte encodings which the Windows build does not appear to include). I would still expect Vim to correctly map UTF-8 encoded characters to Latin1 where the char exists in both though.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I didn't mean for it to come out that way. I'm still annoyed by Vim, cause I spend eight hours yesterday trying to print something out and missed a deadline. Appreciate the effort for trying to find a workaround, but it's a little too much, since I'm from central europe, and use those chars in my daily life - not just occationally. In any case thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Rook: no worries. See my other answer which works for me. If you confirm that's OK I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've cracked it (on Windows at least).

```
:set fileencoding=cp1252
:set encoding=cp1252
```

If I now 'print' a PDF of the text 'ðšdccž', I get the correct output generated.

(CP1252 is Microsoft's amended version of Latin1, [this page](http://www.unicodecharacter.com/charsets/iso8859.html#ISO-8859-1) shows the various Latins.)

---

Incidentally, I also found out a wonderful new command:

```
:dig
```

This lists digraphs: combinations of two letters that you can type (following <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) to get an otherwise hard to enter Unicode character, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> produces 'š'.

Comment: Sorry, no. Of the five letters corresponding to s,d,c(hard),c(soft) and z, I can type in correctly only s and z, and S, D and Z. Those are also the ones that come out in PDF correctly. ... I still think the problem could be in the missing +postscript; trying to find a copy of Vim binaries that has it.

Comment: For diagraphs (for example, for viewing various ascii graphics files and such) I've always found cp437 codepage useful. Certanly works with Vim flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `encoding` is different from the `fileencoding`. Set both to `utf8` and see what happens.

Comment: enc=utf-8, fileenc=nothing, ... printing to pdf gives ... uhmm, well, garbage. A's with dots, and 3/4's.